# Left Outer Join where NULL in Left table

Tags: sql, left-join, outer-join

I have the following tables:

```
ITEM_TABLE            TYPE_TABLE
--------------      -------------------
|Item|Type_ID|      |Type_ID|Type_Text|
--------------      -------------------
|  A |  3    |      |   1   | Table   |
|  B |  1    |      |   2   | Chair   |
|  C |  1    |      |   3   | Bench   |
|  D |  2    |      -------------------
|  E | NULL  |
|  F |  2    |
|  G |  1    |
|  H |  3    |
--------------
```

I want my result to show a meaningful string for the type, so I join the two tables:

```
select 
    it.Item, tt.Type_ID
from 
    ITEM_TABLE it
    left outer join TYPE_TABLE tt
        on it.Type_ID = tt.Type_ID
```

The result is:

```
----------------
|Item|Type_Text| 
----------------
|  A | Bench   |
|  B | Table   |
|  C | Table   |
|  D | Chair   |
|  F | Chair   |
|  G | Table   |
|  H | Bench   | 
----------------
```

Note that there's no row for item E, because it has a `ITEM_TABLE.Type_ID` of NULL, and that value can't satisfy the join condition of `it.Type_ID = tt.Type_ID`.

However, the result I want is:

```
----------------
|Item|Type_Text| 
----------------
|  A | Bench   |
|  B | Table   |
|  C | Table   |
|  D | Chair   |
|  E | NULL    | * note this row here, not present in the actual result
|  F | Chair   |
|  G | Table   |
|  H | Bench   | 
----------------
```

I tried:

```
select 
    it.Item, tt.Type_ID
from 
    ITEM_TABLE it
    left outer join TYPE_TABLE tt
        on it.Type_ID = tt.Type_ID or it.Type_ID is null
```

but that gave the result:

```
----------------
|Item|Type_Text| 
----------------
|  A | Bench   |
|  B | Table   |
|  C | Table   |
|  D | Chair   |
|  E | Table   |
|  E | Chair   |
|  E | Bench   |
|  F | Chair   |
|  G | Table   |
|  H | Bench   | 
----------------
```

that is, three rows for Item E, one with each possible `TYPE_TABLE.Type_Text` value.

So how can I get the result I want, with the join statement realizing that a `NULL` value in the `ITEM_TABLE.Type_ID` column should give a `NULL` value in the `Type_Text` column in the result?

Comment: Maybe use a `RIGHT JOIN`?

Comment: The original query posted should work. Is this the exact same query you are actually using?

Comment: try simple join

Comment: That's certainly _not_ how it works in SQL Server at least - the row should still come through. What kind of database is this? The mistake usually made is filtering on a NULL further down in the query (making it an inner join)

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e1810/1/0).

Comment: Your code selects `tt.Type_ID`, but your result shows `Type_Text`. Please show your actual code and actual results.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select it.Item, tt.Type_ID
from ITEM_TABLE it left outer join
     TYPE_TABLE tt
     on it.Type_ID = tt.Type_ID
```

Will return every row in `ITEM_TABLE`, regardless of whether or not the `on` clause evaluates to `TRUE`, `FALSE`, or `NULL`.  Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/KEKE30582) demonstrating that all rows are returned.  Although the rextester uses Postgres, you will get the same behavior in any database, because this is how SQL works.

Now, if you want a string, you should be selecting the string, not the id.  You can use `coalesce()` to provide another value when there is no match:

```
select it.Item, coalesce(type_text, 'default')
from ITEM_TABLE it left outer join
     TYPE_TABLE tt
     on it.Type_ID = tt.Type_ID
```